# Insert a comment on Google+ activity via any website

Tags: javascript, api, plugins, google-plus

I am trying to build a **Google+ Comment plugin** using `JavaScript` API which will

Note: (I don't want to use any server-side programming language)

List all the current comments on that activity

and

User can post a new comment to that activity after signing-in to Google+ profile.

I have done the first part, I can fetch the comment from an activity.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b508zhp4v2jyfkd/google%20plus%20comments%20plugin.rar) is the basic plugin covering the first part and answer to *(What Have You Tried so Far?)*

Now can anyone suggest me *how do I post comments to that post via website???*

There is a [Comments:insert](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/comments/insert) method, for what purpose it is? (giving it an activity id in **Try it** doesn't insert comment)

Moreover, what is difference between

developers.google.com/+/domains/api/comments

and

developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post activities to public Google+ profiles without the user's consent on each post (using [the Google+ share button](http://developers.google.com/+/web/share), for example). This is done to protect Google+ users' friends streams from getting spam from 3Ps.

This is only true of Google+ accounts that are not privately managed using [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/). Enterprise customers can programmatically manage their business social streams for private instances of Google+. Therefore, the comments and activity write APIs are for [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/) instances of Google and the endpoints are on `+/domains/*` to differentiate the two.

Comment: I want to post a comment to activity ... NOT want to post a new activity

Comment: Is there any way that I can post a comment to an activity?

Comment: Currently, the user must explicitly share content (using the share button) in order to prevent abuse and maintain a good-looking stream.